# Удалить запись из БД через DataGridView, c#, SQL

Tags: c#, sql, база-данных, visual-studio, datagridview

Нужно реализовать по нажатию кнопки удаление, выбранной в DGV, записи из базы данных, желательно синтаксис.

Пробовал так:

```
if (tovarDataGridView.CurrentRow != null)
{
       tovarBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
       tovarBindingSource.EndEdit();
       tovarTableAdapter.Update(this.optDBData.tovar);
       this.tovarTableAdapter.Fill(this.optDBData.tovar);
}
```

Ошибка: Для элемента Update требуется действительный DeleteCommand при передаче коллекции DataRow с удаленными строками.

Нужно чтоб удаляло запись выбранную в DGV даже если это просто ячейка а не вся строка!

Comment: По нажатию какой кнопки? А обработчик у вас какой кнопки? Ошибка говорит о том что поле DeleteCommand у вас не заполнено - туда нужно записать скрипт удаления (желательно с ключём) ключ - отдельная история. Ещё  это Web или десктопное приложение?

Comment: @nick_n_a это WinForms, обработчик обычного Button'a, ну и как мне реализовать удаление? нужно чтоб удаляло запись выбранную в DGV (даже если это просто ячейка а не вся строка)

Comment: [Задайте](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/kda44dwy.aspx) вашему адаптеру свойство [DeleteCommand](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.deletecommand%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а что должно быть в DeleteCommand, какой синтаксис?

Comment: Зависит от DataSource. В sqldatasource синтаксиз sql. В процедурной - имя процедуры. Посмотрите какой синтаксиз в SelectCommand - в DeleteCommand аналогично.

Comment: Удалять ячейку? Вы хотите что бы мы угадали вашу тонкую инженерную мысль, и продолжили её? Вам нужно определится каким элементом ячейка выбрана и удалить именно её. Мне из заголовка вопроса не понятно ни какую строку вы хотите удалить, ни какую ячейку.